# RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 3

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, training-data

### I am having this issue while trying to train my model on a single GPU; I checked the tensors shape  it is resizing fine

```
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 3.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 202, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 28, in fetch
    data.append(next(self.dataset_iter))
  File "c:\users\anaszafar\desktop\train\detectron2\detectron2\data\common.py", line 201, in __iter__
    yield self.dataset[idx]
  File "c:\users\anaszafar\desktop\train\detectron2\detectron2\data\common.py", line 90, in __getitem__
    data = self._map_func(self._dataset[cur_idx])
  File "c:\users\anaszafar\desktop\train\adelaidet\adet\data\fcpose_dataset_mapper.py", line 62, in __call__
    raise
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

---

```
def __call__(self, dataset_dict):
        for i in range(100):
            dataset_dict_temp = copy.deepcopy(dataset_dict)
            dataset_dict_temp = super().__call__(dataset_dict_temp)
            if len(dataset_dict_temp["instances"]) != 0:
                if self.is_train:
                    dataset_dict_temp['instances'] = self.HeatmapGenerator(dataset_dict_temp['instances'], 
                                                                        self.gt_heatmap_stride)
                return dataset_dict_temp
        raise
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code throws an exception without a meaningful error message. Look at the code in `c:\users\anaszafar\desktop\train\adelaidet\adet\data\fcpose_dataset_mapper.py` around line 62 in the function `__call__` and see why your dataset code decided to `raise` an unspecific error.

Comment: I have added the code for the raise, It seems that it does not go in the if condition, meaning len(dataset_dict_temp["instances"] = 0

Comment: @AnasZafar there you go. It seems like you are missing `"instances"` information in your dataset entries. You need to debug your data.

Comment: what I find strange is it is running for a few epochs then crashing with this error; possible conclusion: meaning some of the data may have instance data missing